# Pod install is not working. It fails with some Ruby-related issue

Tags: ios, ruby, pod-install

I am trying this in terminal:

```
pod install
```

Response:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/yaml.rb:3: warning: It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-5.1.0/lib/psych.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-5.1.0/lib/psych.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-5.1.0/lib/psych.bundle' (no such file), '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-5.1.0/lib/psych.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-5.1.0/lib/psych.bundle (LoadError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-5.1.0/lib/psych.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/yaml.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/core_overrides.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:77:in `<module:Pod>'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is a compatibility issue between the Ruby installation and YAML dependencies. Try these steps:

- `brew install libyaml`
- `brew install rbenv`
- Set up [RBEnv](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Rbenv) in your shell by adding the following to your shell profile

  ```
  if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
  ```
- Install the required Ruby version, `rbenv install 2.6.8`
- Set the installed Ruby version as the global default. `rbenv global 2.6.8`
- install bundler by running. `gem install bundler`
- update your [CocoaPods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CocoaPods) installation `gem install cocoapods`
- Then run `pod install` again

Comment: tried these but didnt worked. i found a way. added as answer.

Comment: What is "shell profile"? File *[.profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Operating_system_issues_in_Bash_startup)*? File *[.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)*? File *[.zshrc](https://wiki.debian.org/Zsh#Configuration)*? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Please try these steps:

```
brew install libyaml
brew reinstall ruby
gem uninstall psych
gem install psych
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked with me on a [MacBook Pro M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Sixth_generation_(M1)) system.

In [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)#Terminal):

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

rvm install ruby-2.7.2

sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then restart the terminal:

```
pod init
```

It's working fine.